# Automated testing running twice WebdriverIO cucumber

Tags: angular, testing, cucumber, webdriver-io, wdio

I am making a automated testing in angular with WebdriverIO and cucumber framework. But the test is running twice.
and I want login.feature to run first cause I have some cookie stuff there

Output
[Out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnVJZ.png)

wdio.conf.ts
[wdio.conf.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scX1f.png)

sidbar.feature
[sidbar.feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDOnS.png)

I want it to run only once